# Why risk measures are defined on the space of bounded random variables?

Tags: measure-theory, risk-assessment

I'm reading an article where risk measures are defined on the space of random variable (not necessarily bounded), so I want to understand why risk measures are defined at first (for example in Follmer and Schied) for bounded r.v.